# cakephp 3 baseUrl enabled missing controller

Tags: php, cakephp

in app.php it says:

```
* - baseUrl - To configure CakePHP to *not* use mod_rewrite and to
     *   use CakePHP pretty URLs, remove these .htaccess
     *   files:
     *      /.htaccess
     *      /webroot/.htaccess
     *   And uncomment the baseUrl key below.
```

but when I do uncomment `//'baseUrl' => env('SCRIPT_NAME'),` 
I get Missing Controller error.

Comment: did you remove the .htaccess files? Also: what url give you that error?

Comment: I removed htaccess, but I just keep getting Error: BetaController could not be found. ... this comes in every page, in index specially right away when uncomment the baseurl...

Comment: post one of this url

Comment: on my current setup, there is only index. its in my local computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create htaccess file and write below code

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: where this htaccess should be placed ? Inside webroot or in document root ? I have home > html > webroot, app folder is in same level as html

Comment: The file above should be in the root of you cakephp app directory. The webroot .htaccess should be <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>